# date & counter bash script

Tags: bash, loops, date, count

I need Bash script to generate automatic tags in file.tag.
When the script is called several times during the same day, the COUNTER must be increased.The COUNTER must be reset back to 001 when the date has changed.Thanks

I have tried

```
#!/bin/bash 
touch file.tag 
counter=0 
date=$(date +"%y.%m.%d") 
echo $date.$counter > file.tag
```

Comment: Good luck with that.

Comment: `#!/bin/bash
touch file.tag
counter=0
date=$(date +"%y.%m.%d")
echo $date.$counter > file.tag`

Comment: and now im here and i cant move

Comment: just to make you move, so 1) check if the script has been called in this day, i.e. store some information in bash shell 2) if not set the counter to 0, else (i.e. if else in bash ) 2) increase counter in bash i.e. increment a variable in bash, rest everything you have done in the above script, try some search engine like google, bing, yahoo, duckduckgo

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
[[ ! -f ./file.tag ]] && touch file.tag

declare -i counter
dt=$(date +'%y.%m.%d')
counter=$(grep -c "${dt}" file.tag)
(( counter++ ))

printf '%s.%03d\n' ${dt} ${counter} >> file.tag
```

This script :

- counts the number of occurences of current date in file.tag
- increments this counter
- adds date and counter to file.tag

If date if not matched, `grep -c` will return 0, starting another day with 001

Answer (score 0):

I noticed in your example that file.tag always has only one line: the last tag, right?

Give this version a try (tested and checked with shellcheck):

```
#!/bin/bash 

touch file.tag 
date=$(date +"%y.%m.%d") 
counter=0
if [ -s file.tag ]
then
  lastline=$(tail -1 file.tag)
  if [ "${date}" = "$(expr "${lastline}" : "^\([0-9.][0-9.]*\)[.][0-9][0-9]*$")" ]
  then
    counter=$(expr "${lastline}" : "^[0-9.][0-9.]*[.]\([0-9][0-9]*\)$")
    counter=$((counter + 1))
  fi
fi
printf "%s\n" "${date}.${counter}" > file.tag
```

The script checks if the file.tag is not empty.

If not empty, it extracts the last date from the file.tag and compare it to the current date.

If the dates are equal, then it extracts the last value of the counter from the file.tag and increment it

finaly it updates the file.tag with the new tag